# Parallelize tasks using polly

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, polly

Let's say I have a list of objects `myObjs` of type `List<Foo>`.

I have a polly policy :

```
var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().RetryForever();
```

which i want to run methods on in parralel, but keep retrying each as they fail.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObjs.Count; i++)
{
  var obj = myObjs[i];
  policy.Execute(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => obj.Do(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
}
```

Will this be called in parallel and retry each obj? So if `myObjs[5].do()` fails, will only that get retried while other objects just get executed once?

Also, am I supposed to use the `ExecuteAsync()` method which accepts `Func<Task>` instead of the `Execute(Action)` one as shown in the example? `Do()` is just a synchronous method, being launched in a separate thread.
Actual code looks like this where `each()` is just a foreach `wrapper()`

```
_consumers.ForEach(c => policy.Execute(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Consume(startFromBeg), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)));
```

EDIT:

I tried the code:

```
class Foo    
{
        private int _i;
        public Foo(int i)
        {
            _i = i;
        }
        public void Do()
        {
            //var rnd = new Random();
            if (_i==2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("err"+_i);

                throw new Exception();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(_i);
        }
}
var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry(3);
var foos=Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => new Foo(x)).ToList();
foos.ForEach(c => policy.Execute(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Do(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)));
```

but am getting result:

> 0 1 err2 3 4 5

I thought it would retry 2 a few more times, but doesn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever owns the tasks must wait for them somehow.  Otherwise, [exceptions will be ignored](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) and the code will end before the tasks actually complete.  So yes, you should probably be using `policy.ExecuteAsync()` instead.  It would look something like this:

```
var tasks = myObjs
    .Select(obj => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => obj.Do(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning))
    .ToList();

// sometime later
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Yes, this works now. I used Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); in my sync method and used policy's RetryAsync() version.